# One Hot Encoding for this kind of tables

Tags: python, pandas

| Order ID | Item Name |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | apple |
| 123 | orange |
| 456 | apple |
| 456 | grape |

I want to one hot encode the above table and get the desired output as below.

| Order ID | Apple | Orange | Grape |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 456 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Please advise how to do this in Python.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using [pd.crosstab()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html).

**Note:** the usage of `rename_axis()` here is just to remove the name of the index column which is actually `itemName`.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'orderID':[123, 123, 456, 456, 456], 'itemName':['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'grape', 'orange']})
>>> df
   orderID itemName
0      123    apple
1      123   orange
2      456    apple
3      456    grape
4      456   orange

>>> df = pd.crosstab(df.orderID,df.itemName).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
>>> df
   orderID  apple  grape  orange
0      123      1      0       1
1      456      1      1       1
```